# Next.js 13 - Chakra UI - Dark Mode White Screen Flash - FOUC (flash of unstyled content)

Tags: typescript, next.js, loading, next.js13, chakra-ui

When I refresh the page in my application built with Next.js 13 /app folder and Chakra UI:

- The screen flashes white for a second before showing the dark theme.
- The internationalization and font settings are also back to default for a blink of an eye before applying the saved preferences.

It seems there's a delay in accessing and applying settings from *cookies* and *localStorage* upon refresh. Not sure if [this GitHub](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/2430) issue is related.

Can I fix that issue by incorporating a loading bar such as NProgress or a similar one?

I tried using `loading.tsx`, without success:

```
import { Spinner, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Text } from '@chakra-ui/layout';

const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <Flex
      w="100vw"
      h="100vh"
      direction="column"
      color="white"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Text>Just give us a moment...</Text>
      <Spinner
        thickness="4px"
        speed="0.65s"
        emptyColor="gray.200"
        color="blue.500"
        size="xl"
        mt="1rem"
      />
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default Loading;
```

In fact, that loading bar didn't even appear. What's wrong?

### src/app/[locale]/layout.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from 'next-intl';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ locale: 'en' }, { locale: 'bg' }];
}

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: {
    locale: string;
  };
};

const AppLayout = async ({ children, params }: Props) => {
  let messages;
  try {
    messages = (await import(`../../messages/${params.locale}.json`)).default;
  } catch (error) {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <NextIntlClientProvider locale={params.locale} messages={messages}>
          {children}
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

### src/app/[locale]/(main)/layout.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Metadata } from 'next/types';

import { InitializeChakra } from '@/components/InitializeChakra';
import { Header } from '@/components/Header';
import { Footer } from '@/components/Footer';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Quant Logistics',
  description: 'Optimization model for production scheduling',
  keywords: 'quant, logistics, quant logistics, optimization model, optimization model for production scheduling',
};

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const AppLayout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <InitializeChakra>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </InitializeChakra>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "logistics",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/next-js": "^2.1.5",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "next": "14.0.0",
    "next-intl": "^2.21.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://griko.medium.com/prevent-fouc-on-next-js-chakra-ui-68df8b1b63ab this is a good post but it is for /pages router. I'm using the new /app router.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { CacheProvider } from "@chakra-ui/next-js";
import { ChakraProvider, ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import theme from "@/theme";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import ReactQueryProvider from "@/provider/react-query-provider";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export function Providers({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <ReactQueryProvider>
        <CacheProvider>
          <ColorModeScript initialColorMode="dark" />
          <ChakraProvider resetCSS theme={theme}>
            {children}
          </ChakraProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
      </ReactQueryProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

If you are using next js 13 with chakra ui then here is quick fix you can apply to stop startup flickering issue in next js. add color mode script

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It didn't change after I added `CacheProvider`. `ColorModeScript` however made it even worse. Now only the navigation bar remains in white mode for a second, everything else is dark.